Extending Discrete Time theorems to Continuous Time
Consider the following theorem about Discrete Time Markov Chains (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eharchol/Probability/chapters/chpt25.pdf#page=12):
Theorem 25.12: For an irreducible, aperiodic finite-state Markov chain with transition matrix P, we have:
$$
\pi_j = \frac{1}{m_{jj}} > 0
$$
where

$m_{jj}$ is the mean time between visits to state $j$ and $\pi_j = \lim_{n \to \infty} (P^n)_{ij}$ (i.e. recurrence time)
$\pi_j$ represents the steady-state probability of being in state $j$.
$m_{jj}$ is the mean recurrence time, or the expected time for the chain to return to state $j$ given that it is currently in state $j$.
$(P^n)_{ij}$ is the $(i, j)$-th entry of the $n$-th power of the transition matrix $P$, which gives the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps.

Now, consider a Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC):
In the case of a Continuous Time Markov Chain, we define its "Rate Matrix" as the instantaneous rate of transitioning between any two states:
$$
Q_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \cdots & q_{1m} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \cdots & q_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{m1} & q_{m2} & \cdots & q_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$q_{ii} = -\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{m} q_{ij}$$
We use the Kolmogorov Forward Equations to "recover" the time-dependent probability transition matrix (I like to think of $q_{ij}$ as the "average" transition rate in some very small amount of time from state i to state j ... across all possible times):
$$
\lim_{{t \to 0}} \frac{{P_{ij}(t)}}{t} = 
\begin{cases} 
q_i & \text{if } i = j \\
q_{ij} & \text{if } i \neq j 
\end{cases}
$$
$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = P(t)Q$$
$$P(t) = e^{tQ}$$
$$\exp(Qt) = I + Qt + \frac{1}{2!} Q^2t^2 + \frac{1}{3!} Q^3t^3 + \ldots$$
We then define the Embedded Discrete Chain (Jump Process) : This is used to determine where the chain will go to next and at what time this transition will happen
For all $m$ states in the Markov Chain, define a set of $m$ holding rates $\lambda_i = \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_m$.
Here, $\lambda_i = \sum_{j} q_{ij}$. For example,  $\lambda_1 = q_{11} + q_{12} + q_{13} + ... + q_{1m}$
If we are currently in state $i$, then the probability distribution of the "time at which the next transition will happen" is said to have the following probability distribution (an Exponential Distribution):
$$f_T(t) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t}$$
And if we are current in state $i$, the probability of transitioning to any other state is given by (note that this $P_{ij}$ is time INDEPENDENT - this is the Jump Process):
$$P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$
Here, $q_{ij}$ itself is the average transition rate (across all small time intervals) over all possible times between states (i,j). Thus, $P_{ij}$ can be thought of as the average of the average transition rate between (i,j) across all possible times (i.e. time independent transition probability).
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$e^{tQ} = I + tQ + \frac{(tQ)^2}{2!} + \frac{(tQ)^3}{3!} + \frac{(tQ)^4}{4!} + \cdots$$
My Question:

Is it possible to apply Theorem 25.12 to determine the mean recurrence time in a CTMC?
Is it possible to determine the probability distribution of $m_{jj}$ for a CTMC (i.e. probability distribution of recurrence times) ?
Is it possible to determine the probability distribution of $m_{jj}$ for a Discrete Time Markov Chain (i.e. probability distribution of recurrence times) ?
Thanks!

References:

Proving The Fundamental Theorem of Markov Chains
https://people.unipmn.it/bobbio/DIDATTICA/MODQ/ctmcfig.pdf : This is a reference which shows how to derive the probability distribution of absorption times in a CTMC. I am not sure if this can be adapted to extend the answer to determine the probability distribution of recurrence times


Check out section 1.8 in these notes https://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-CTMC.pdf . The idea is indeed to exploit the result for the embedded discrete time chain, but things look a little different because you have to worry about the clock.

Also as a general comment, your question includes a ton of standard background on continuous time Markov dynamics, which is really not needed. In my opinion, it helps to write concise questions, because that improves the chance that someone actually reads it! You can, if you like, add a link to explain what a CTMC is, but someone with no idea about these will probably not be able to help you anyway, and someone who knows all this will just be irritated because they don't see the actual question. Of course, this is only a suggestion :)

Thank you for your kind words! I agree that perhaps I write too much in my questions ... I do this for a few reasons

I like to write mathematical background of the question. This serves as a quick intro for future students who might stumble across my questions .... and also, the more I write, the more places there are for me to make mistakes :) this way I realize that perhaps my fundamental understanding of the necessary background is incorrect ... and if someone points this out, I can try to correct this background knowledge

But I do agree, I will try to write shorter and more concise questions :)

coming back to the original question: is it possible to derive a probability distributions for recurrence times in DTMCs and CTMCs? I was able to do this for absorption times .... but I am wondering if this is possible for recurrence times as well

If you have absorption times, you already have recurrence times. To study the recurrence time of a state $j$, take a starting distribution of $\nu(i) = P(i|j)$, and consider the Markov chain $\tilde{P}$ such that $\tilde{P}(i|k) = P(i|k)$ if $k \neq j,$ and $\tilde{P}(i|j) = \delta_{ij}$. Then state $j$ is absorbing for $\tilde{P}$, but until you visit $j$ again, the dynamics of $\tilde{P}$ and $P$ are identical, so the absorption time for $\tilde{P}$ is the same as the recurrence time for $j$ under $P$ minus 1 (to account for the first step). Same trick works in continuous time.
